# Problem on Maclaurin expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am very confused by the Maclaurin expansion of power functions. For example trying to find the expansion of $(1+x^{2})^{1/6}$ by computing the derivatives and then dividing by the factorial to find the coefficient is very time consuming because the numbers get too big. I assume I can also use the binomial theorem to do this but the exact way eludes me. I would really appreciate if you could help me with this because I am getting very frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

expand just$$f(X)=(1+X)^\frac 16$$

and in the end, replace $X$ by $x^2$.

$$f'(0)=\frac 16$$
$$f''(0)=\frac 16 (\frac 16 -1)$$
....

Comment: I was confident that this was the way.My problem is mainly on how to expand (1+x)^1/6.

Comment: @MichaelP. The derivatives are not difficult to get.

Comment: Isn't $f'(0) = 0$ in the original (with the $x^2$)?

Comment: @Makina $f(x)=(1+x)^\frac 16$ not $(1+x^2)^\frac 16$.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you did there

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Newton’s Generalized Binomial Theorem to evaluate the function.$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$Now replace $x$ with $x^2$ and set $n$ equal to $1/6$.